# public FirebaseUser getCurrentUser () how does it work?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I try to understand how FirebaseUser getCurrentUser() works.
According to spec it returns signed user or null.
But I think that they mean that "last signed user in this device".
Right ?

Comment: As its name implies the `getCurrentUser()` method returns the **currently signed in user**. There is no `getLastSignedInUser()` method. If you're having trouble making this method work, or are getting different results, please update your question with the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

No, it's the currently signed in user, just as the name of the method suggests.  If the user signs out, there is no current user, and the method returns null.

Comment: But this data should be saved on local device. Which flow of this function ?

Comment: Should it?  Is that what the product documentation suggests?

Comment: This is my assumption. I don't know @Doug Stevenson

Comment: If you think the product is doing the wrong thing (I don't think it is), then you should file a bug report instead of posting to Stack Overflow.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features